# Do all covalent nitrates on heating decompose to give nitrogen dioxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Being covalent we can conclude that they will on heating decompose completely, but will they give only $\ce{NO2}$ and not any other oxide is the question.

It is observed in $\ce{Pb(NO3)2, AgNO3,}$ and also $\ce{LiNO3}$ (the anomalous behaviour of $\ce{Li}$) that they decompose on heating to give $\ce{NO2}$ and the above mentioned nitrates possess good amount of covalent character. So as a rule can I remember that all covalent nitrates decompose to give $\ce{NO2}$ or there are any exceptions to it?

Comment: I would not classify those as 'covalent' nitrates.

Comment: [Xenon nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenon_nitrate) has unusual mechanism of decomposition.

Comment: What criteria do you use to state that the lead and silver nitrates possess good amount of covalent character ?